# Migrating Quality Center test plans to a another QC infrastructure

Tags: quality-center

**What we want to do:**

We have a requirement to transfer the test plans form a HP Quality Center project to a different stakeholder who has his own Quality Center instance.

**What we do not want to do:**

We do not want to give the entire project. We just want to share the test plans from specific folder in a project so that they can use them in their Quality Center instance.

**Question:**

Can you please let me know what is the best way to do this?

We are having some issue with creating new project. Initial plan was to create project copy over the project and delete the data and retain only specific data. and share the copy of the database.

Thanks,
vinay